Case Statement when DateTime is Equal to DateTime
I am trying to count number of long and short trades taken by a trading system.
Every trade in the dataset has an associated Close Date (formatted as 03/12/2024 4:45). Some trades are single-position trades, while others are multiple-position trades. The close dates on the latter are identical.
Total trade count, with no distinction between long or short, is findable with count_distinct(Close Date).
Every Close Date also has an associated Action - "Buy" for long trades and "Sell" for short trades. To create an accurate distinction between long and short trades, multiple position trades (which have the identical Close Date) need to be counted as a single trade.
I've tried case statements that attempt something like When Close Date = Close Date And Action = "Sell" Then "Short Trade", but this doesn't produce an accurate result.
Is a case statement the appropriate way to accomplish what I'm after?
